# C/C++ fork(), pipes(), and execvp() question

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, pipe

I'm trying to develop a simple Unix shell simulation. The part that i think I'm currently stuck on is understanding how `execvp` works. I've tried to do some research into it but not having much luck.

Basically I'm making a child process with `fork()`, and a pipe. I'm redirecting the `STDOUT` to my pipe's write `fd`. And lastly I'm calling my `execvp` from my child process. My `execvp()` call is just a program that outputs a simple string.

I am then trying to read this string from the parent and use that as input for my second `execvp()` program. This program simply outputs whatever it reads in.

The issue I'm having is my first program is being called from `execvp()`, and then it's just outputting the string straight to the terminal.

I guess my question is, does a program executed with `execvp()` not carry the `STDOUT` (my pipes write end) of the program is was created in? And if not, how would I go about forcing that to write into my pipe instead of terminal? Can I put my `execvp` inside a write call?

```
else if(commandLine[i] == "|"){ 
            pid_t pid2;
            pid2 = fork();
            t = i;
            if (pid2 == 0){ // in child of child 
                close(pipe1fd[0]);
                dup2(pipe1fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                execvp(commandLine[i-1], commandLine);
            }
            else{
                close(pipe1fd[1]);
                dup2(pipe1fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                wait(0);
                execvp(commandLine[i+1], commandLine);
                goto BACK;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to create pipe. Just make stdin of second process in pipeline same as stdout the first process in pipeline

Comment: Hmm okay can I do that from inside my fork child process? With dup2?

Comment: Is it possible that the output is coming thru the pipe, as expected ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I threw some extra strings into my second program and it's not even outputting. In fact, I put a few output strings on top of my else{ loop and it's not even printing those. I'm not sure if its just skipping the loop entirely or if my STDOUT is messed up. Kinda seems like my else{ loop isn't even being executed which is weird because I have basically the exact same execution happening in a different program and it works fine. The only thing I can think of is that this is technically the child of a child, not sure if that would change anything?

Comment: It would increase the chance of an answer to include a complete example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). File descriptors are inherited across exec unless they have the close-on-exec property.